# geocoding error in django-easy-maps

Tags: python, django, google-maps, maps, geocoding

I cant get django-easy-maps to work. It has "geocoding error" error and I am not sure why and how to solve this.

based on this:
https://github.com/bashu/django-easy-maps
I first ran this:

```
pip install django-easy-maps
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'easy_maps',
)

EASY_MAPS_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ___0123456789' (not this is not my key but i just put it as example'
```

in my template for the html

```
{% extends 'employee/base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% block page %}

    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading bg-blue">
          <h4 class="panel-title text-center text-white">
            My Map
          </h4>
        </div>
          <div class="panel-body">

                    {% load easy_maps_tags %}
                    {% easy_map "Russia, Ekaterinburg, Mira 32" 300 400 %}


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

{% endblock %}
```

I run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

But it doesnt show any map in the page. It has this

It has this "geocoding error" in the html generated file.

```
  <!-- HTML map container -->
  <div id="map-canvas-1"

    class="easy-map-googlemap">

    <!-- geocoding error -->
  </div>
```

What is the problem and what is the right way to setup easy-maps on django ?

Comment: have you generated an api key from the google dashboard??

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my configuration. I have noticed that the address seems to be case sensitive to a parameter I don't understand

An address can work if all the string is in lower case but the same address with one char to uppercase and it doesn't work anymore.
And this doesn't mean that the address needs to be in lowercase.

For example in my case :

That address works: 28 rue bardin, 92110 clichy

but this one not : 
28    rue bardin, 92110 **C**lichy

and in others situations, it's inverted some uppercase are needed for the address to work properly